# Is there an app that just posts to Twitter and Facebook?

Tags: facebook, twitter

I'm looking for a Mac (and/or iPhone) app that allows me to post to both Twitter and Facebook in one action. The trick is that I only want the app to push data. I don't want it to pull down any content from either services. The reasoning behind this is that I want to be able to make a post without moving the reference point in Twitter for the last thing I've read (a la TweetDeck).

Does such an App exist?

*Note: There doesn't seem to be a good way to do this yet. The answer I accepted is as close as it looks like you can get currently.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [If This Than That](http://ifttt.com/) to do stuff like this. It's like glue for internet services.

There's a bunch of recipes that post Facebook wall updates to Twitter automatically for you. Here's one: http://ifttt.com/recipes/1854

This would save you from having to open a Twitter client. But now you've got posts in Facebook truncated in Twitter because of the length restrictions.

Why not just switch to a better Twitter client? One that has [TweetMarker](http://tweetmarker.net/) support?

If you want to try the best-of-the-best but bleeding edge check out the currently-in-beta [Tweetbot for OS X](http://tapbots.com/blog/tweetbot/tweetbot-for-mac). It's a sweet, sweet client and with TweetMarker support you can open it, tweet a new tweet, and then close it down and it doesn't lose your position. It even syncs the position other TweetMarker-enabled clients.

If you're not willing to run beta software try [Twitterrific](http://iconfactory.com/software/twitterrific/) -- also has TweetMarker support and also doesn't lose your position if you open, tweet, and then close it down again.

If you use one of these Twitter clients and combine them with an IFTTT recipe that reposts and tweet you make with the `#fb` hashtag to Facebook you'll be all set. [Here's the recipe I use](http://ifttt.com/recipes/553).

Comment: This doesn't do exactly what I'm looking for, but it's close enough for jazz.

Answer (score 0):

**Drafts -app [here](http://agiletortoise.com/drafts)**

> It tries to connect different apps together but I would not count too much on it: they have no goal to add OCR -support, support for natural hand-writing and usability things for Twitter such as the 140 limit-display.
>
> Even though my initial impression was very bad about the app and its future development, it is quite cool app: it connects to Appigo Todo and many other apps.